# MongoDB - find document based on date stored as array

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb

Sample document:

```
{
"_id":"ADANIGREEN",
"longcount":6,"
shortcount":0,
"trend":"Y",
"shortdate":[{"$date":"2020-07-13T00:00:00.000Z"}],
"longdate":[{"$date":"2020-07-20T00:00:00.000Z"}]
}
```

I need to query document like the SQL query below:

```
select _id from sample_document where longdate='2020-07-20T00:00:00.000'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far? are you pymongo or mongoengine?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the `$in` operator, which can check if one array has elements which are contained with another array:

```
db.sample.find( { longdate: { $in: ["2020-07-20T00:00:00.000"] } } )
```